# What does 夢がない said by this speaker mean?

Tags: meaning

A and B waiting for C to bring more leaked photos of XXX.

> A「C、早く来ないでござるかなぁ……XXXの写真、早く見たいでござるよ」
>
> B「どんどん過激になってきてますからね～。今度はパンモロとかかもしれませんよ！？」
>
> A「それは夢がないでござるよ！　パンツはチラリと見えるくらいが至高でござる！」

それは夢がないでござるよ - "that" (full panty shot) is not a dream, just a
glimpse....

それは夢がないでござるよ has to mean something closer to  "that's a pipe dream is it not" to make logical sense, but how does it get there?

Comment: Are you concerned with ないでござる or 夢がない?

Comment: それは夢がないです as a whole, i find it hard to fit into the context

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you seem to have ignored the basic grammar; が is a subject marker and ～がない means "there is no ～".

- 夢で(は)ない。 That is not a dream.
- 夢がない。 There is no dream.

So それは夢がないでござるよ literally means "There is no dream in it (=パンモロ)" or "パンモロ has no dream". I think you can now guess the meaning, but here 夢がない ("having no dream", "dreamless") means something like "does not stir one's imagination", "has no room for imagination", "too explicit and thus not exciting", etc. 夢がある means "promising", "dreamy", "fantastic", "not very realistic but exciting anyway", etc.

Comment: Maybe "That leaves nothing to the imagination" is how it might be phrased in English.

Comment: @kandyman Thank you, I learned what it means from Google Image Search :)